# How do I display a filtered list of objects from an array in typescript?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, web, filter

How do I display a filtered list of BED objects from my BED ARRAY? I just need a simple filter (bStatus = "Available") for loop for reference.

My BED object has a Bed Status, which shows if it's Available or Occupied (for a hospital system), and I want it to display ONLY Beds which are Available. (when bStatus == "Available")

The code provides a part from my NgOnInit() from my component.ts, I'm able to display all the beds available, but as I'm new to Angular and Typescript, I do not know how to add filter into my code.

```
this.bedService
        .query()
        .pipe(
            filter((mayBeOk: HttpResponse<IBed[]>) => mayBeOk.ok),
            map((response: HttpResponse<IBed[]>) => response.body),
        )
        .subscribe((res: IBed[]) => (this.beds = res), (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message));
```

The expected output should be a list of beds which have bStatus = "Available". Right now it displays all the beds in my array, which include bStatus = "Available" and "Occupied".

Answer (score 4):

You can simply run [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get the available beds.

```
.subscribe((res: IBed[]) => {
  this.beds = res.filter(obj => obj.bStatus === 'Available');
})
```

Comment: Thank you, do I replace this over (this.beds = res)?

Comment: @Ken yes you may

Comment: what if i want to put multiple filters, do I use && like obj.bStatus === 'Available' && obj.Type = 'A'? is the && operator legit in Angular?

Comment: @Ken Yes, it is valid syntax is JavaScript and TypeScript. Basically, you can change the filter callback to something like this: `res.filter(obj => obj.bStatus === 'Available' && obj.Type = 'A');`

Comment: I have tried it and it does not return anything instead, the obj.bStatus === 'Available' works but if I add another parameter the code breaks. Do you have any idea what could be behind it?

Comment: @Ken Sorry, I mistyped. It should be `res.filter(obj => obj.bStatus === 'Available' && obj.Type === 'A');` triple equals for checking type and value equality, whereas single equal is for assignment of values/references

Comment: yes, I did it with 3 equal bars, but apparently, it breaks the code.. .subscribe((res: IBed[]) => (this.beds = res.filter(obj => obj.bStatus === 'Available' && obj.bClassType === 'A'),  (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)));

Comment: it is still not working, anyway, thanks for your help i will try to troubleshoot it. @wentjun